# Proving constructors are partial functions in Coq

Tags: coq

With an inductive definition like:

```
Inductive A :=
 mkA : nat -> A.
```

Proving constructors are partial functions can be encoded as:

```
Lemma constructor_functional :
 forall i1 i2, mkA i1 <> mkA i2 -> i1 <> i2.
```

Although it is trivial to prove, doing so for every defined type sounds weird.

Is there a tactic to encode this property? Or some equivalent in a library? I did not find anything in ssreflect though by searching `(_ <> _)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can state a generic lemma that subsumes this result for every Coq function. Since constructors like your `mkA` are just functions, the result applies to them as well.

```
Lemma function_functional :
  forall (X Y : Type) (f : X -> Y) (x1 x2 : X),
    f x1 <> f x2 -> x1 <> x2.
Proof.
  intros X Y f x1 x2 H1 H2.
  apply H1.
  now rewrite H2.
Qed.
```

This statement is actually the contrapositive of the following one from the standard library.

```
Lemma f_equal :
  forall (X Y : Type) (f : X -> Y) (x1 x2 : X),
    x1 = x2 -> f x1 = f x2.
```